# How to send emails using Django All auth?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm trying to send emails for signup/account verification etc using django allauth, and it has worked correctly during development using the console as the email backend, however now I'm trying to send emails in using gmail, I'm getting the below error:

SMTPAuthenticationError at /accounts/password/reset/
(535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials q1-20020adfdfc1000000b0022e049586c5sm11068760wrn.28 - gsmtp')

I've tried following the steps in the article mentioned in the error message, but they haven't worked.
Not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help would be much appreciated!

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'example@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*****'
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure the setting is correct.
As described [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)  ​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password. But you can enable `Less secure app access` in your developer console. The risks are on your own ([Here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en) is a guide to enable).

Final point: Do not hard code password in your source, read it from the environment.

UPDATE:
There are multiple guides online about how to configure Gmail for SMTP access.
For example see [here](https://www.jotform.com/help/392-how-to-use-your-gmail-account-as-your-email-sender-via-smtp/)

Comment: I can't change the Less secure app access, because I only have a personal account- I'm not doing this for an organisation and don't have a Google workspaces account. Do I need to create one for this?

Comment: You need to configure an account for this purpose, there are multiple guides online. It's better to use a non personal account for security reasons.

Comment: I've read the guide provided, and I've already followed these steps, this is what has been laid out in my settings. This is also for JotForm, not Django.